# Why server send a lot of dns request to?

Tags: dns, centos-7

A CentOS7 server send a lot of DNS request to the same server name

Why it happen? How can I check it?

In the output of tcpdump I get something like:

```
xxx.xxx.69.13.57607 > xxx.xxx.22.1.53: [bad udp cksum 0x63ec -> 0xd1d8!] 19796+ AAAA? server.mydomain.com. (43)
15:33:28.337676 00:aa:7f:65:71:aa > 00:50:aa:b8:33:aa, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 203: (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 60421, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 189)
xxx.xxx.22.1.53 > xxx.xxx.69.13.57607: [udp sum ok] 34515* q: A? server.mydomain.com. 1/3/3 server.mydomain.com. [1d] A 10.150.68.12 ns: mydomain.com. [1d] NS ns1.mydomain.com., mydomain.com. [1d] NS ns2.mydomain.com., mydomain.com. [1d] NS ns4.mydomain.com. ar: ns4.mydomain.com. [1d] A 192.115.46.1, ns2.mydomain.com. [1d] A xxx.xxx.22.1, ns1.mydomain.com. [1d] A xxx.xxx.4.1 (161)
15:33:28.337784 00:aa:7f:65:71:aa > 00:50:aa:b8:33:aa, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 136: (tos 0x0, ttl 60, id 60422, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 122)
xxx.xxx.22.1.53 > xxx.xxx.69.13.57607: [udp sum ok] 19796* q: AAAA? server.mydomain.com. 0/1/0 ns: mydomain.com. [2h] SOA ns1.mydomain.com. hostmaster.mydomain.com. 79384 900 3600 604800 7200 (94)
15:33:28.337973 00:50:aa:b8:33:aa > 00:aa:7f:65:71:aa, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 85: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 21196, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
```

Any idea are welcome

Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the relevant lines/logs?

Comment: I update my question with relevant logs

Comment: In the above tcpdump, there is a query for two DNS RRs, IPv4 A and IPv6 AAAA. That's perfectly normal when you have IPv6 enabled in your CentOS. However, you mention "send a lot of DNS request to the same server name". Can you elaborate on that, please. What is "a lot" in your server? Once a minute? Once every 15 minutes?